# project euler problem17 vb code bug

Tags: vb.net

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?

NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

my answer is coming 21148. i cant find the mistake here is my code in vb
the answer should be 21124

```
    Dim length As UInt32 = 11
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
For i = 1 To 999
    If i / 10 < 1 Then
        single_digit(i)
    ElseIf i / 10 = 1 Then
        ten()
    ElseIf i / 10 > 1 And i / 10 < 2 Then
        ele_twe_thi(i)
    ElseIf i / 10 >= 2 And i / 10 < 10 Then
        multiple_10(Math.Floor(i / 10) * 10)
        single_digit(i Mod 10)
    ElseIf i = 100 Then
        single_digit(i / 100)
        length += 7
    ElseIf i Mod 100 >= 11 And i Mod 100 <= 19 Then
        length += 10
        single_digit(Math.Floor(i / 100))
        ele_twe_thi(i Mod 100)
    ElseIf i Mod 100 = 10 Then
        length += 3
        single_digit(Math.Floor(i / 100))
        length += 10
    Else
        length += 10
        single_digit(Math.Floor(i / 100))
        multiple_10(Math.Floor((i Mod 100) / 10) * 10)
        single_digit(i Mod 10)
    End If
Next
MsgBox(length)
End Sub
Private Sub single_digit(num)
If num = 1 Then
    length = length + 3
ElseIf num = 2 Then
    length = length + 3
ElseIf num = 3 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 4 Then
    length = length + 4
ElseIf num = 5 Then
    length = length + 4
ElseIf num = 6 Then
    length = length + 3
ElseIf num = 7 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 8 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 9 Then
    length = length + 4
End If
End Sub
Private Sub ele_twe_thi(num)
If num = 11 Or num = 12 Then
    length = length + 6
ElseIf num = 13 Or num = 14 Or num = 18 Or num = 19 Then
    length = length + 8
ElseIf num = 17 Then
    length = length + 9
ElseIf num = 15 Or num = 16 Then
    length = length + 7
End If
End Sub
Private Sub multiple_10(num)
If num = 20 Then
    length = length + 6
ElseIf num = 30 Then
    length = length + 6
ElseIf num = 40 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 50 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 60 Then
    length = length + 5
ElseIf num = 70 Then
    length = length + 7
ElseIf num = 80 Then
    length = length + 6
ElseIf num = 90 Then
    length = length + 6
End If
End Sub
Private Sub ten()
length = length + 3
    End Sub
```

Comment: i dont want other solution . Just want to know whats wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time the program reaches 100, 200, 300 etc. is it adding an "and" unnecessarily?

Comment: that would explain why you are 24 over as it reaches a new hundred 8 times and the "and" adds 3 letters

Comment: Not really an answer, rather a comment